# Columns in string query not being delimited when executed

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, formatting

I have a SQL statement set as a string. Whenever I execute the call in my application locally I am getting an error where it seems the SQL is not being built out properly and not delimited by comma between two different columns. I am wondering why this is happening.  There is an Iif statement with an expression in between these columns, but I'm not sure syntactically how to make the field delimited.

The error I get is:

> Exception caught: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll ("Invalid column name 'CONTACT_EMAILT'.")

Below is the existing query string:

```
strSQLXL = "SELECT V.VND_NBR
  ,VND_NAME
  ,C.CONTACT_NAME
  ,C.CONTACT_EMAIL," & IIf(MyApp.objUserShadow.CountryUserSelected = 1, "T.[NAME] AS CONTACT_TYPE ", " ") & "  
FROM dbo.TBL_VND_VBU AS V
INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_VND_VBU_CONTACT AS C
ON V.VND_NBR = C.VND_NBR AND V.CRY_CD = C.CRY_CD
INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_VND_TYPE AS T
ON C.CONTACT_TYPE = T.ID 
WHERE V.CRY_CD = " & VMS.objUserShadow.CountryUserSelected
```

The output when I execute this per the Intellitrace logs are as below:

```
SELECT V.VND_NBR
      ,VND_NAME
      ,C.CONTACT_NAME
      ,C.CONTACT_EMAILT.[NAME] AS CONTACT_TYPE
FROM dbo.TBL_VND_VBU AS V
INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_VND_VBU_CONTACT AS C
ON V.VND_NBR = C.VND_NBR AND V.CRY_CD = C.CRY_CD
INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_VND_TYPE AS T
ON C.CONTACT_TYPE = T.ID 
WHERE V.CRY_CD = 1
```

The output should be:

```
SELECT V.VND_NBR
          ,VND_NAME
          ,C.CONTACT_NAME
          ,C.CONTACT_EMAIL
          ,T.[NAME] AS CONTACT_TYPE   
    FROM dbo.TBL_VND_VBU AS V
    INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_VND_VBU_CONTACT AS C
    ON V.VND_NBR = C.VND_NBR AND V.CRY_CD = C.CRY_CD
    INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_VND_TYPE AS T
    ON C.CONTACT_TYPE = T.ID 
    WHERE V.CRY_CD = 1
```

Is there something I am missing to format it like the output above? I have tinkered around a lot but can't seem to get it to build properly in the right format. Any suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: @marc_s I have added the sql server 2008 tag.  Thanks!

Comment: I guess you need to add space before T.[NAME]: `IIf(MyApp.objUserShadow.CountryUserSelected = 1, " T.[NAME]` because in the string result its getting concatenated to CONTACT_EMAIL.

Comment: @jonathana thanks for the effort, but still I am getting the same error

Comment: if you put a breakpoint after strSQLXL what do you get? also are you sure that is the piece of code that is getting executed? I have tested it and its works as expected...maybe there are more relevant parts of your code that you can show

Comment: The example code cannot produce the documented output. Specifically, there's a comma in the string before the `IIf`: `C.CONTACT_EMAIL,"`. This comma after the `CONTACT_EMAIL` column name would have to be in the output, but it's not. So please update the code and/or output to be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
strSQLXL = "SELECT V.VND_NBR, VND_NAME, C.CONTACT_NAME, C.CONTACT_EMAIL" & _
           IIf(MyApp.objUserShadow.CountryUserSelected = 1, ", T.[NAME] AS CONTACT_TYPE ", " ") & _
           "FROM dbo.TBL_VND_VBU AS V INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_VND_VBU_CONTACT AS C " & _
           "ON V.VND_NBR = C.VND_NBR AND V.CRY_CD = C.CRY_CD " & _
           "INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_VND_TYPE AS T ON C.CONTACT_TYPE = T.ID " & _
           "WHERE V.CRY_CD = " & _
           VMS.objUserShadow.CountryUserSelected
```

Comment: Iif() is a VBA function.

Comment: I know what it is, `IIf` evaluates all of its arguments prior to returning a value back, while `IF` is an operator that executes like a short-circuiting conditional, only evaluating the true or false argument; much difference.

Comment: Don't you and the OP have the comma in the wrong place?  The comma after `C.CONTACT_EMAIL` should be in the IIF block: ", T.[NAME] AS CONTACT_TYPE " or else you have a comma right before the FROM section on a false evaluation..

Answer (score 0):

The comma is in the wrong place: it should only be there if the additional column is to be included:

```
Dim contactTypeColumn As String = If(MyApp.objUserShadow.CountryUserSelected = 1, ", T.[NAME] AS CONTACT_TYPE ", " ")

strSQLXL = "SELECT V.VND_NBR
  ,VND_NAME
  ,C.CONTACT_NAME
  ,C.CONTACT_EMAIL" & contactTypeColumn & "  
FROM dbo.TBL_VND_VBU AS V
INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_VND_VBU_CONTACT AS C
ON V.VND_NBR = C.VND_NBR AND V.CRY_CD = C.CRY_CD
INNER JOIN dbo.TBL_VND_TYPE AS T
ON C.CONTACT_TYPE = T.ID 
WHERE V.CRY_CD = " & VMS.objUserShadow.CountryUserSelected
```